chakra-ui resizes image when dragging it to the right edge of the screen
I'm implementing a simple drag component (based on interaction pane). If I use just img without chakra-ui, I can drag the image beyond the right edge of the scree without any issues.However, if I use chakra-ui, and drag an img towards the right edge of the screen, the image resizes and becomes smaller and smaller to align it's right edge with screen's right edge. No issues when moved beyond top, left and bottom edges of the screen.
codesandbox implementation with chakra-ui is here.
codesandbox implementation without chakra-ui is here.
with chakra-ui
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState({ x: 400, y: 200 });

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <PanPinchZoom offset={offset} setOffset={setOffset}>
        <img
          src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/GitHub-Mark-ea2971cee799.png"
          style={{ border: "2px solid green" }}
        />
      </PanPinchZoom>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

function PanPinchZoom(props) {
  const { offset, setOffset, children } = props;

  const [dragPositionStart, setDragPositionStart] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [dragPositionOffsetStart, setDragPositionOffsetStart] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

  function handlePointerDown(event) {
    console.log("pointerDown");
    const newDragPositionStart = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    setDragPositionStart(newDragPositionStart);
    setDragPositionOffsetStart({ ...offset });
    setIsDragging(true);
  }

  function handlePointerMove(event) {
    if (isDragging) {
      // console.log("pointerMove");
      const dragPositionEnd = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
      const deltaX = dragPositionEnd.x - dragPositionStart.x;
      const deltaY = dragPositionEnd.y - dragPositionStart.y;
      setOffset({
        x: Math.round(dragPositionOffsetStart.x + deltaX),
        y: Math.round(dragPositionOffsetStart.y + deltaY),
      });
    }
  }

  function handlePointerUp(event) {
    console.log("pointerUp");
    setIsDragging(false);
  }

  return (
    <div
      id="pan-pinch-zoom-parent"
      onPointerDown={handlePointerDown}
      onPointerMove={handlePointerMove}
      onPointerUp={handlePointerUp}
      style={{
        touchAction: "none",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      }}
    >
      <div
        id="pan-pinch-zoom-child"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: `${offset.x}px`,
          top: `${offset.y}px`,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


without chakra-ui
just remove ChakraProvider wrapper in App component. Rest stays the same.
export default function App() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState({ x: 400, y: 200 });

  return (
      <PanPinchZoom offset={offset} setOffset={setOffset}>
        <img
          src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/GitHub-Mark-ea2971cee799.png"
          style={{ border: "2px solid green" }}
        />
      </PanPinchZoom>
  );
}

There are no other CSS anywhere.

same issue if I use chakra's Image component. link
